# minimum x-value of the superview’s bounds?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

What does this expression "**minimum x-value of the superview’s bounds**" mean in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/) regarding Autolayout in a `UIScrollView`?

> ...some notes regarding Auto Layout support for UIScrollView:
>
> - In general, Auto Layout considers the top, left, bottom, and right edges of a view to be the visible edges. That is, if you pin a view to
>     the left edge of its superview, you’re really pinning it to the
>     minimum x-value of the superview’s bounds. Changing the bounds origin
>     of the superview does not change the position of the view.
> - The UIScrollView class scrolls its content by changing the origin of its bounds. To make this work with Auto Layout, the top, left,
>     bottom, and right edges within a scroll view now mean the edges of its
>     content view.

1) As I know by default **bounds** of a view is (0, 0, width, height). So x is **0**.

2) How could a view have **more** x values to take minimum on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Autolayout constraints for any view is generally in relation with the ***visible*** bounds of the view but when it comes to a `UIScrollView`, the Autolayout constraints are in relation with the scrollView's `contentView`.
*Obviously, because a `scrollView` is, well... supposed to scroll.*

---

Suppose a `scrollView` has a `contentSize` of something like:

```
myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000);
```

now...
Say, in this `scrollView` you have a `subView`, something like:

```
UILabel *lblTest = [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[lblTest setText:@"Where am I?"];
[myScrollView addSubView:lblTest];
```

Before Scrolling:

- `myScrollView.contentOffset.y` will be `0`
- `myScrollView.bounds.y` will be `0`
- `myScrollView.frame.origin.y` will be `0`
- `lblTest.frame.origin.y` will be `0` (*and will be visible*)

After Scrolling (*to bottom*):

- `myScrollView.contentOffset.y` will change to `900`
- `myScrollView.bounds.y` will **also** be `900`
- `myScrollView.frame.origin.y` will **still** be `0`
- `lblTest.frame.origin.y` will be `-900` (*and no longer visible*)

This is what the Apple Documentation means by:

> The UIScrollView class scrolls its content by changing the origin of
>   its bounds.

Now...
If Autolayout was in relation with the visible bounds of `UIScrollView` then no matter how much you scrolled, the `UILabel` would not scroll up.
but...
Since Autolayout in a `UIScrollView` goes in relation with the scrollView's `contentSize`, the Autolayout contraints work within it with relation to the scrolling functionality.

So...
When you use Autolayout for `subViews` in a `scrollView`, it will be relational to the `scrollView`'s actual size and not the visible size.

Answer (score 0):

apple docs says ask: The UIScrollView class scrolls its content by changing the origin of its bounds.

1) so scrolling can change bounds.x, and than **x will be not 0**
bounds property is **usually** (0, 0, width, height), **but not always**

2) the minimum means: the top, left, bottom, and right edges within a scroll view now mean the edges of its content view.